# MySQL Query - avoid Duplicate Entry

Tags: mysql, database

The Userdatabase has usernames with "?" ending on the name. For example username: "Alex?"
Instead of deleting it I'm trying to replace this "?" with a "2" to avoid duplicate entries. The Problem is, there a still duplicate entries even with 2 at the end. I need a query, which automatically changes the 2 to 3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9 until no duplicate entry exists anymore. I was doing this manually until now, but honestly I changed over 200 lines and I guess there are more than 1000.

Some Ideas?

The Query I use:

```
UPDATE `userdatabase`
SET `username` = replace(`username`, "?","2")
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not familiar mysql update syntax in detail, but if table "userdatabase" have unique id column may be possible something like that

```
replace(username, "?", (select count(*) from userdatabase db where db.username = username and db.id < id))
```